# Comic with device causing lock-in syndrome

Tags: story-identification, comics

I am looking for a comic (or graphic novel) I read about 8 years ago [*], where one of the characters had a device that induces immediate [lock-in syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locked-in_syndrome). Towards the end of the story, one of the antagonists is punished as the device is used on him: the victim falls to the ground and the person holding the device announces that he is now able to communicate only by opening and closing his eyes, then leaves the antagonist to his destiny.

Any help appreciated.

Additional info: I vaguely remember that the device holder was dressed a sort of magician with a top hat.

[*] EDIT: the book was in bookstores at that time; however, I believe it was a collection of older stories. It was a full-color comic, possibly with a superhero main character.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you be more specific about when "a few years ago" was?  You should also check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for story id questions to see if they help you recall any details to [edit] into your question.

Comment: Hello DavidW, thanks for the feedback. I edited my question per your suggestion.